# Codeigniter redirect function fails if # sign in the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, session

I am using the redirect in the PHP Codeigniter library to redirect the user to the last accessed URL if they are not logged in to our portal.

$uri = $this->ci->uri->uri_string();
$this->ci->session->set_flashdata('redirect' , $uri);

It works fine except in one case:

When there is a # sign in the URL for ex:

http://myview.com/library#portal/sh2qQXF3SxAbJ

It redirects back to http://myview.com/library

It does not take the address after the # sign.

In our front end, we use a Backbone.js to detect a # sign and fire up what needs to be done next with Javascript..

My question is if there is a way to store the whole URL in the codeigniter session variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part with the `#` is called the fragment, and it is never transmitted to the server (unless you do it manually, as a parameter in AJAX or something). Thus, your PHP will never see it in a query URL.

Comment: Hi Amadan, thanks for the info.  Any way to get around it?  How would/should a redirect work in this case?  How would we store it?

Comment: Catch it on the client side with `location.href` (whole thing) or `location.hash` (just the fragment), and send it to the server; then use that instead of `$this->ci->uri`. I don't quite know the flow of your application (and I've never used codeigniter), so I can't give you the specifics on when and where to transmit it.